# Why is my cron job not working?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, cron, scp

I have a cron job I have installed through `crontab -e` that backups a certain file from the server and saves it to my home drive with a time stamp. I have executed it to work all the time to test it but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
 * * * * * /home/arran/hourly.bash > /home/arran
```

There must be something I'm missing out?

Comment: Does the script work when ran from the command line outside of cron? If not, there may be some error message on the terminal that could assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: what is `/home/arran`? Your home directory? Maybe you should name a file to write the output into.

Comment: Yeah the script works fine when run in the command line and every time I run it a new file is created. I just want the cron job to do that but every hour

Answer (score 3):

You're redirecting the output of your command to a directory, which will fail. Redirect to a file instead:

```
* * * * * /home/arran/hourly.bash > /home/arran/hourly.log
```